# What is an archive classifier in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In a `build.gradle`, inside of `task.register`, I can find this

```
group 'build'
description 'Build the project for the R1 target and assemble a zip with the APK and the client library'
classifier variantNameCap
```

I've read that *classifier* should be relative to the archive. But what is exactly the concept of *classifier* in Gradle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a concept taken from maven - see https://maven.apache.org/pom.html and search for `classifier`.

The classifier distinguishes different artifacts build from the same project.

A classifier could be something like `fat` or `shaded` where all dependencies are in a fat jar and/or shaded.

Classifiers like `debug` or `source` are quite common. The debug artifact will contain all debug information and the source artifact will contain the source files.